# Runtime error "cannot find symbol ByteValue$$Native" when using ChronicleMap

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, chronicle-map

The project I'm working on is made of several components - several independent libraries that are compiled to JARs, and a main project that references them. All are written in Scala.

I'm using ChronicleMap internally in one of those libraries, using a custom value class with its own marshaller.
When running the main project I get these errors:

```
 /net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Native.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
public class ByteValue$$Native implements ByteValue, Copyable<ByteValue>, BytesMarshallable, Byteable {
                                          ^
  symbol: class ByteValue
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Native.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
public class ByteValue$$Native implements ByteValue, Copyable<ByteValue>, BytesMarshallable, Byteable {
                                                              ^
  symbol: class ByteValue
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Native.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
  public void copyFrom(ByteValue from) {
                       ^
  symbol:   class ByteValue
  location: class net.openhft.chronicle.core.values.ByteValue$$Native
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Heap.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
public class ByteValue$$Heap implements ByteValue, Copyable<ByteValue>, BytesMarshallable {
                                        ^
  symbol: class ByteValue
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Heap.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
public class ByteValue$$Heap implements ByteValue, Copyable<ByteValue>, BytesMarshallable {
                                                            ^
  symbol: class ByteValue
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Heap.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
  public void copyFrom(ByteValue from) {
                       ^
  symbol:   class ByteValue
  location: class net.openhft.chronicle.core.values.ByteValue$$Heap
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Native.java:20: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Native.java:25: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Native.java:30: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Native.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
    if (!(obj instanceof ByteValue)) return false;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ByteValue
  location: class net.openhft.chronicle.core.values.ByteValue$$Native
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Native.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
    ByteValue other = (ByteValue) obj;
    ^
  symbol:   class ByteValue
  location: class net.openhft.chronicle.core.values.ByteValue$$Native
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Native.java:66: error: cannot find symbol
    ByteValue other = (ByteValue) obj;
                       ^
  symbol:   class ByteValue
  location: class net.openhft.chronicle.core.values.ByteValue$$Native
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Heap.java:15: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Heap.java:21: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Heap.java:26: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
  @Override
  ^
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Heap.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
    if (!(obj instanceof ByteValue)) return false;
                         ^
  symbol:   class ByteValue
  location: class net.openhft.chronicle.core.values.ByteValue$$Heap
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Heap.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    ByteValue other = (ByteValue) obj;
    ^
  symbol:   class ByteValue
  location: class net.openhft.chronicle.core.values.ByteValue$$Heap
/net/openhft/chronicle/core/values/ByteValue$$Heap.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
    ByteValue other = (ByteValue) obj;
                       ^
  symbol:   class ByteValue
  location: class net.openhft.chronicle.core.values.ByteValue$$Heap
```

This only happens when running the project from Intellij IDEA, not when running from command line.

Also, if I set up a standalone project that uses the same ChronicleMap with the same custom class and marshaller, I don't have any problem running it from the IDE. The problem only happens when running the project that uses my library from the IDE.

So I'm thinking this may or may not be related to the class loading order, or maybe some dependencies that are missing in the IDE.

Is there anything I can do to find out why I can't run from the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

that certainly does look like some sort of configuration issue.

You may be able to get some more information on what classloading is going on by running the code with `-XX:+TraceClassLoading` and comparing the output between successful/unsuccessful execution of your program.